# regex 1-9999 for form validation

Tags: regex, numbers

I am trying to write some form validation, I need one of the inputs to be 1-9999. I know nothing about regular expressions ( never used them before) and here is my first attempt

```
/^([1-9][1-9]|[1-9]|[1-9]\d|9999)$/
```

Does not seem to want to work, can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: If you're talking about HTML form, consider `<input type="number">`

Comment: What language are you using? Why not just use integer comparison? It seems stupid and **way overkill** to be using regular expressions to verify something like this.

Comment: If you have never worked with regular expressions I recommend you to read some tutorial (there are lots out there). If you don't any time you need a regex you'll have to comeback here. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the below regex,

```
^(?:[1-9][0-9]{3}|[1-9][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9])$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kF4pU2/7)

Comment: There's a substantially shorter version that would work for this: `/^(?:[1-9][0-9]{0,3})$/`

Comment: Heck, even this would work: `/^(?:[1-9]\d{0,4})$/`

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't exclude zero, but `/^\d{1,4}$/` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this

```
^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])$
```

Comment: This pattern works perfectly for my use case in Angular: 
`<input type="number" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="play-time" [(ngModel)]="playTime" min="1" max="9999" minLength="1" maxlength="4" pattern="^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])?$" digitOnly required />`

Answer (score 0):

To exclude zero values but include non-zero ones with leading zeros:

```
([1-9]\d{0,3})|(\d[1-9])\d{0,2}|(\d{2}[1-9])\d?|(\d{1,3}[1-9])
```

Answer (score -2):

This Regex should not match numbers that start with 0 a part from 0

Regex: `/^(?!(0\d))\d{1,4}$/`

Regex (Exclude Zero): `/^(?!(0))\d{1,4}$/`

Test: https://regex101.com/r/zfCKel/2

Comment: This actually does not work for excluding 0.